# libGDX Shadow not showing on floor

Tags: java, android, libgdx, shadow

I'm trying to add shadows to the bottom of my model but the shadow isn't showing at the bottom. Can anyone help? This is what I tried using the deprecated `DirectionalShadowLight`:

```
        environment = new Environment();
        environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, .4f, .4f, .4f, 1f));
        environment.add(new DirectionalLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -1f, -0.8f, -0.2f));

        shadowLight = new DirectionalShadowLight(1024, 1024, 60, 60, 1f, 300);
        shadowLight.set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -1f, -.8f, -.2f);
        environment.add(shadowLight);
        environment.shadowMap = shadowLight;
        shadowBatch = new ModelBatch(new DepthShaderProvider());

        camera = new PerspectiveCamera(67, screenWidth, screenHeight);
        camera.position.set(0, 6, 2);
        camera.direction.set(0, 0, -4).sub(camera.position).nor();
        camera.near = 1;
        camera.far = 300;
        camera.update();




   private void renderSanta(GL20 gl) {
        gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_CULL_FACE);
        // /****************
        shadowLight.begin(Vector3.Zero, camera.direction);
        shadowBatch.begin(shadowLight.getCamera());
        shadowBatch.render(santaModel);
        shadowBatch.end();
        shadowLight.end();
       // ********************/
        modelBatch.begin(camera);
        modelBatch.render(santaModel, environment);
        modelBatch.end();
       gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_CULL_FACE);
       gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    }



   private void renderBackground() {
        viewMatrix.setToOrtho2D(0, 0, 480, 800);
        spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(viewMatrix);
        spriteBatch.begin();
        spriteBatch.enableBlending();
        spriteBatch.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        spriteBatch.draw(background, 0, 0, 480, 800);
        spriteBatch.draw(hammock, 0, 800 - 500 - 95, 182, 95);
        spriteBatch.disableBlending();
        spriteBatch.end();
    }


@Override
    public void draw(float delta) {
        GL20 gl = Gdx.gl;
        gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        renderBackground();
        renderSanta(gl);
    }
```

[image: Output showing shadow]

**EDIT:**

So like Xoppa commented, I added a "plane" under the santa model but still the shadow wasn't shown:

```
 ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
        modelBuilder.begin();
        MeshPartBuilder mpb = modelBuilder.part("parts", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal | VertexAttributes.Usage.ColorUnpacked,
                new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.WHITE)));
        mpb.box(0, -1.5f, 0, 7, 1, 7);
        mpb.setColor(1f, 0f, 1f, 1f);
        model = modelBuilder.end();
        instance = new ModelInstance(model);
        instance.transform.setTranslation(0, -5, -3);

  public void renderModel() {        
        shadowLight.begin(Vector3.Zero, camera.direction);
        shadowBatch.begin(shadowLight.getCamera());
        shadowBatch.render(instance);
        shadowBatch.end();
        shadowLight.end();

        modelBatch.begin(camera);
        modelBatch.render(instance, environment);
        modelBatch.end();
    }

 @Override
        public void draw(float delta) {
            GL20 gl = Gdx.gl;
            gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            renderBackground();
            renderModel();
            renderSanta(gl);
        }
```

Updated output still now showing shadows [image]

**Edit 2:** Thanks to Xoppa I was able to make the shadow appear:

[image: Updated Image]

Comment: Based on your code, it looks like "the bottom" isn't part of your 'santaModel', which is the only model you're rendering using your shadow map.

Comment: @Xoppa Sorry but I'm a noob. Do I load a new 3d model and place underneath the santamodel? Should i create a box/cube model and render using the shadow map? Can you please help with some code? I'll really appreciate :)

Comment: Yes, a box or plane will do. If you prefer, you can add it to your model using you modeling application (e.g. blender). That way, you don't have to change your code.

Comment: @Xoppa  I've added it but still things remain the same. I did by code. Please check my updated question showing the new screenshot output

Comment: I forgot to mention that the default shader uses per vertex shading. You need to add more vertices or use a different shader. The latter is the probably the better option for you and is explained here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/ModelBatch#default-shader you only have to use these shader files (also linked in that wiki page): https://gist.github.com/xoppa/9766698.

Comment: @Xoppa Hmm, it seems complex. Can you share some code here on how to achieve it please?

Comment: Sure, copy those two files from the gist to your assets folder and in your create() method use something like this: `modelBatch = new ModelBatch(Gdx.files.internal("vertex.glsl"), Gdx.files.internal("fragment.glsl"));`

Comment: @Xoppa I've done that but it crashes when I call shadowBatch.render(santaModel); Please see my updated question with the crash report (under Edit 2:). How can I fix the crash please?

Comment: Read the comment again: shadowBatch != modelBatch.

Comment: @Xoppa You're right. I've fixed the crash by using modelBatch but still the shadow doesn't show on the "floor" :(   Is there anything else I need to do besides changing how the modelbatch is created?

Comment: It looks like you're using a different shadowmap for your ground model. Don't do that, just add a line to render the ground in the same batch as your santa model. This indicates that you're not understanding the fundamentals. You better start at the beginning, work your way through my tutorials first: https://xoppa.github.io/blog/basic-3d-using-libgdx/.

Comment: @Xoppa Whoaa! It's working now. Thank you. Originally the plan was to cast shadow on my 2d background sprite but i guess that's impossible now.

Comment: Glad it works for you now. Everything is possible of course, but spritebatch natively doesn't support 3d lights indeed. In this tutorial I explain how to render sprites using ModelBatch, which works with shadows as well (see the gif at the bottom of the page): https://xoppa.github.io/blog/a-simple-card-game/. However, that's probably not something you should look into right now.

Comment: @Xoppa Indeed it's something I shouldn't look into now :) By the way, my shadow looks like it needs some antialiasing. Please see the updated screenshot in my original question. Is there anything I can do to fix this or it's normal?

Comment: That sounds like a new question, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Libgdx+antialiasing. Also, increasing the size of the shadowmap or decreasing the viewport of the light will help you get better results.

Comment: alright thanks a lot